# java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedList

Tags: java, exception, casting, linked-list, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` where the key is of type `String` and the value is of type `LinkedList` of type `String`.

So basically, here's what I'm trying to do.

```
while (contentItr.hasNext()) {
    String word = (String) contentItr.next();
    if (wordIndex.containsKey(word)) {
        LinkedList temp = (LinkedList) w.get(word); //Error occurs here
        temp.addLast(currentUrl);
    } else {
        w.put(word, new LinkedList().add(currentUrl));
    }
}
```

The first time that I add a key,value pair, I receive no error. However, when I try to retrieve the linked list associated with an existing key, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedList.
```

I don't have a possible explanation of why this exception occurs.

Comment: w is a HashMap I described in the opening sentence.

Comment: Can you show it's definition? It looks to me like it's defined wrong.

Comment: I just defined it as HashMap w = new HashMap();

Comment: This question is a really good example why we need to declare generic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
while (contentItr.hasNext()) {
    String word = (String) contentItr.next();
    if (wordIndex.containsKey(word)) {
        LinkedList temp = (LinkedList) w.get(word);
        temp.addLast(currentUrl);
    } else {
        LinkedList temp = new LinkedList();
        temp.add(currentUrl);
        w.put(word, temp);
    }
}
```

The problem, as you can see, was in the line that adds a new element to the Map - the method `add` returns a boolean value, and that's what was being added to the Map. The code above fixes the problem and adds what you intended to the Map - a LinkedList.

As an aside note, consider using generic types in your code, in that way errors like this can be prevented. I'll try to *guess* the types from your code (adjust them if necessary, you get the idea), let's say you have these declarations somewhere in your program:

```
Map<String, String> wordIndex = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, LinkedList<String>> w = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>>();

List<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator<String> contentItr = content.iterator();
```

With that, the piece of code in your question can be safely written, avoiding unnecessary casts and type errors like the one you had:

```
while (contentItr.hasNext()) {
    String word = contentItr.next();
    if (wordIndex.containsKey(word)) {
        LinkedList<String> temp = w.get(word);
        temp.addLast(currentUrl);
    } else {
        LinkedList<String> temp = new LinkedList<String>();
        temp.add(currentUrl);
        w.put(word, temp);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As per the comments below - assuming that you actually *can* replace the `LinkedList` by an `ArrayList` (which might be faster for some operations) and that the *only* `LinkedList`-specific method you're using is `addLast` (which is a synonym for `add`), the above code can be rewritten as follows, in a more Object-Oriented style using interfaces instead of concrete classes for the containers:

```
Map<String, String> wordIndex = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, List<String>> w = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator<String> contentItr = content.iterator();

while (contentItr.hasNext()) {
    String word = contentItr.next();
    if (wordIndex.containsKey(word)) {
        List<String> temp = w.get(word);
        temp.add(currentUrl);
    } else {
        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        temp.add(currentUrl);
        w.put(word, temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, nice, but I like @yshavit's recommendation of strongly typing the `HashMap`.  Most container methods benefit nicely from being declared with generic arguments.

Comment: I just edited my code to show you an example of how that can be accomplished - adapt it to your actual needs!

Comment: Unless you need any LinkedList-specific methods, I would make it a `Map<String,List<String>>` -- not a `Map<String,LinkedList<String>>`. There are various discussions on SO and elsewhere about coding to interfaces. And btw, if you don't need that LinkedList functionality, consider an `ArrayList` instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist

Comment: OP is using a `LinkedList`-specific method: `addLast`, so using a `List` is out of the question

Comment: @Óscar López `addLast` is identical to `add`, so if that's the only `LinkedList`-specific method, I would still go with `List`.

Comment: @yshavit thanks for your comments, I just edited my answer to take them into account

Answer (score 6):

`List.add` returns `boolean`, which is being autoboxed to `Boolean`. Your else clause is creating a LinkedList, calling a method on it (`add`) that returns boolean, and putting the resulting autoboxed Boolean into the map.

Do you know about generics? You should type w as a `Map<String,List<String>>` instead of just a Map. If you did that, this error would have been caught at compile time.